# Blank Eevee render on all files

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render something with the Eevee render engine in the new Blender 2.8 beta version, but the render shows up only blank. This occurs on all blender files, and these files render fine on other computers.
Perhaps the Microsoft Surface Pro I am using just isn't up to the task?

Cycles render works fine.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

It'd be great if I could get some help!
Thanks

Comment: If it renders fine on other computers the answer lies in what is different on the specific hardware you are dealing with. Does the computer in question have a dedicated GPU? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#cpu-rendering and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140842/can-you-render-using-the-cpu-with-eevee

Comment: @cegaton No, the device I am using does not have a dedicated GPU, so I'm guessing that since EEVEE doesn't use the CPU when rendering, the GPU on the device just isn't capable. If you know a way around this it'd be great, otherwise there's probably no fix.

Comment: I read the second one, first didn't load for me. So, no cpu rendering. Got it.
Looks like I'm sticking with Cycles